# New Font for TeX

Tags: fonts

Inspired by Greta Thunberg's handwriting, a new font named "GretaGrotesk" has just been published. When will it be available for TeX/LaTeX?

Font characteristics are here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f6JdU9jG6J69mngi5-xYwbKXtCcnslJo/view

Comment: You can use any OTF font you want, with XeTeX / LuaTeX. There's a question about this on this site somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GretaGrotesk}
\begin{document}

01234567890

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW

.,-<>!"§\$\%\&/()=? 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should mention that this document should be compiled with either XeTeX or LuaTeX, i.e. the command `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: You'll get a usefull error message when compiling with `pdflatex`

Comment: @user187802 Ha! If people read error messages, this forum would be almost empty.

Comment: I also think that letting users find out the hard way that it does not work is an approach that not everyone may like.